# What are the requirements for logging SIC time?

Tags: faa-regulations, logging

I am going from KPRC to KVGT with a friend in his C-182.  I don't have a high-performance endorsement, but can I -- as a private pilot -- log as SIC at any time during our flight?

If so, what rules do I have to follow?

From what I understand:

- I can log SIC time since the aircraft is a SEL
- I can't log landings, obviously
- And SIC time really doesn't mean anything

Am I right in assuming those things?

Comment: "log SIC time" is the phraseology used by the FAA, not "log as SIC". See the FAA document I referenced in the checked answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can basically log SIC time if you are a ***required crewmember*** and are not able to log PIC time.

So, generally in an airplane like a C-182 which is certified for only one pilot, you can't log SIC time because you aren't a required crewmember.

There are a few exceptions though, like being a safety pilot for the PIC while they are using a view limiting device (like an IFR hood), etc.

SIC time is not pointless because it still adds to your total time!

As far as landings, you can log them only if you are the sole manipulator of the flight controls, in which case you are allowed to log **PIC** time (even though you aren't allowed to **act** as the PIC since you don't have your high performance endorsement).  Oddly enough, in this situation the pilot who is acting as PIC isn't allowed to log it because they don't meet any of the requirements for doing so. It's one of the only situations where the PIC isn't allowed to log it as such.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17837/discussion-between-lnafziger-and-rbp).

Comment: So if you are a student, and a required crewmember, do you log both "student" and "SIC" time?

Comment: @ssummer Depends on the student.  If they are a student pilot (do not have their pilot license yet) then they are never a required crewmember unless they are solo (in which case they log PIC time).  Once they get their license then it depends on whether or not they are PIC or not (but yes, if they are not the PIC and are a required crewmember then they would log SIC time and Dual Received."