# Should DUAL flight be logged as SINGLE PILOT TIME?

Tags: easa-regulations, logging

1. **Should DUAL flight be logged as SINGLE PILOT TIME?**
2. Should **total** SINGLE PILOT TIME + **total** MULTI PILOT TIME = TOTAL TIME?
3. In what cases SELF could be specified in PIC NAME on DUAL flight?

**EASA regulations applied! (Hungary)**

Many thanks

Comment: Which country's regulations are you asking about? If it's the US, we have some questions that might help: [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/19500/62), [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/12735/62).

Answer (score 1):

1) If you are under training in a single pilot aircraft (e.g. C172), it is logged as dual in single pilot. If you are under training in a multi pilot aircraft (e.g. A320), it is logged as dual in multi pilot.

2) Correct.

3) If dual (under training), the PIC name should always be the name of your instructor. The only time you use SELF is if **you** were PIC, and therefore the flight cannot be dual.

See EASA Part FCL; FCL.050: https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/Part-FCL.pdf

Comment: I'm not challenging your answer, but it would be great if you could link to the underlying regulations. On this site we have a general preference for including sources and references where possible.