# How to log Flight Training Device (FTD) and Full Flight Simulator (FFS) time in the US?

Tags: faa-regulations, logging, flight-simulator

I just completed the ATP CTP Course in the US as a pre-requisite for taking the ATM Written Exam. During the course, according to the syllabus, I have flown 4 hours of B733 in a FTD (fixed-base) and 6 more hours of B733 in a FFS (motion-base). The Simulator is FAA Certified. How should I log this pilot time in my logbook, according to the US Regulations? Do this simulator time counts as total time?

Comment: See [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/19500/62) for information on "total time". It isn't defined by regulation. I believe airlines sometimes go into more detail than the regulations in how time is logged, e.g. they may distinguish between PIC time from acting as PIC vs. PIC time from being the sole manipulator of the controls. Good general advice for logging is to use an electronic logbook and log as much detail as possible about each flight or sim session. Then you can easily find time that meets whatever criteria you may be asked for.

Comment: Your flight instructor should be the one to answer that, and maybe even write the first entry for you as an example of how to log the time.