# How to sign hours on Logbook if doing aerial work in right seat on single pilot aeroplane?

Tags: general-aviation, easa-regulations, logging

Recently I got an offer to work during the incoming summer as survey pilot, but since I do not have the required hours for insurance I can not be the PIC on left seat. So they proposed to be on the right seat until getting enough experience and then switch on. Can I sign those hours on the right if the aircraft is certify for single pilot operation? How?

Comment: This is a *legal* question. You cannot expect reliable answers for that here, only personal opinions.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle questions about regulations are on topic here, such as [What are the requirements for logging SIC time?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8969/1696) (FAA)

Comment: Also, I noticed you tagged "EASA regulations" so I assume that you don't care what the FAA has to say about the matter.  Is that correct?

Comment: The owner can name you as a pilot if he really wants you.  Not sure if that works in Europe though.

Comment: Well, I am going to work in Europe under EASA rules, for that reasons I tagged EASA regulations. But if you got some info for FAA as well could be interesting to share some light.

Comment: Are you asking if a) you can fly from the right seat with another pilot in the left seat, or b) fly solo from the right seat?

Comment: What makes you think which seat you're in changes whether you can be PIC or not?

Comment: @Pondlife a) fly from the right seat with another pilot in the left and log PICus.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about EASA regulations but in the US you can log PIC time whenever you are the sole manipulator of the controls and properly rated to fly the aircraft.  In the US there is a distinction between the legal PIC (person legally responsible for the flight) and PIC time which is the person actually flying the airplane.  Since the plane is certified for only single pilot operations you can only log PIC time not SIC time and only when you are the sole manipulator of the controls.  The FAA regulations for logging time can be found in [FAR 61.51](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.51).